# discord.js error on run - DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

when I run my discord.js bot, it instantly crashes with this long error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^
 
DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET /api/v8/applications/"641878231481450499"/guilds/"815113248001097738"/commands
```

Full error at: https://pastebin.com/qtaTWCeM (yes I know my token is in there, I've regenerated it)

My code is public on Github: https://github.com/ASOwnerYT/asowneryt-discord-bot

I have no idea what this error means and how to fix it, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Http status code `401` means `unauthorized`. Which means, the credentials you provided are either missing or invalid. Make sure to add valid credentials for your bot. Your token might be revoked for some reason, you could regenerate a new one to be sure.

Comment: I'm 100% sure my token is valid, I've checked and regenerated the token multiple times.

Comment: Then it's a permissions issue. Re-add your bot using `applications.commands` scope as well. Example: `https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=BOT_ID&permissions=8&scope=applications.commands bot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6060964/variable) wrote in the comments, this was a permissions issue, and all I had to do was re-invite the bot with the `applications.command` scope. For example: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=BOT_ID&permissions=8&scope=applications.commands