# NPM UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: mongodb, npm, discord, discord.js

I've set up a 20.04 Ubuntu server in a virtual machine and on AWS to run an uno bot that is no longer hosted by the developer. (https://github.com/Exium1/UnoBot) I've been following someone's guide on how to set it up (https://github.com/DaanWet/UnoBot/blob/master/documentation/Install.md) but it is failing when i go to start it.

I get the following error:

```
(node:14998) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET /api/v9/gateway/bot
    at RequestHandler.request (/home/ubuntu/UnoBot/node_modules/eris-sharder/node_modules/eris/lib/rest/RequestHandler.js:75:15)
    at Client.getBotGateway (/home/ubuntu/UnoBot/node_modules/eris-sharder/node_modules/eris/lib/Client.js:2135:36)
    at ClusterManager.calculateShards (/home/ubuntu/UnoBot/node_modules/eris-sharder/src/sharding/clustermanager.js:507:38)
    at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/UnoBot/node_modules/eris-sharder/src/sharding/clustermanager.js:179:41)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
(node:14998) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by
 rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14998) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js pro
cess with a non-zero exit code.
```

could anyone help with resolving this issue?

Comment: The problem isn't the fact that the promise rejection is unhandled. The real problem is that you're receiving a HTTP 401 Unauthorized response from the server. Do you have authentication for this server so that you can try again?

Comment: It is a discord bot, there is a token that you put into the config.js file so i should have authentication

Comment: Permission issue? Reinvite the bot with the right ones.

Comment: Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266954/discord-js-error-on-run-discordhttperror-401-unauthorized-on-get.

Comment: The error simply refers to an invalid token you need to add a valid token [here](https://github.com/Exium1/UnoBot/blob/c7eb7bc53b80106f60713b24ed550671198c7dc5/utils/configExample.js) and rename it to config.js

Answer (score 0):

In order to address the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` warning that was logged, you can fix it by adding the following to your code:

```js
process.on("unhandledRejection", console.error);
```

This will log the error much more clearly, and will prevent your console from being filled up with those warnings.

As for what @mmenschig said, they are indeed correct. Ensure that you have the correct token passed into `<Client>.login()`.